# Clearly defined OSM data? (can a meadow be within a nationalpark)

Tags: openstreetmap

I conduct an analysis of OSM-data for farmland, meadows, vineyards and orchards.

I am not completly sure, if these objects are excluded of proteced land (national parks, etc.)

Does OSM define those objects clearly or is it possible that a meadow can lie within a nationalpark for instance?

Comment: National Parks are admin boundaries, farmland/meadow etc are land use/land cover characteristics. I see no reason why any of them can't be inside a national park, unless the particular country's definition of a national park means it has to be a "wilderness" that can't contain managed land. Have you looked for examples and counterexamples in OSM maps?

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dnational_park for reference, also the idea of a "National Park" is very different between nations. A national park in the USA is very different to the UK.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, I am aware of this but still for me agriculture within nationalparks (in germany) makes not much sense. I will extract nationalparks from my areas.

Comment: With OSM anything can be (and often is) with in anything. `horse=yes`

Answer (score 0):

You find the definitions in the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dprotected_area) and the german view of protection areas in the Bundesnaturschutzgesetz. E.g. for national parks its §24. It doesn't necessarily exclude farmland.